# Laravel 10: Get the full JSON API Response (not truncated)

Tags: json, laravel, logging, truncate

I have integrated my app with a third-party app for payments, regarding successful payments the app is able to receive the complete API response (shared below) and also insert successfully into the database table, the issue is noted for the unsuccessful payments where the response is different than the successful payment response and I am not able to correctly format the API response and also insert into the database table as it happens for the successful payments. So, what I am trying to do is:

1. Get the complete unsuccessful API response on the Laravel logs;
2. Remove the backslashes to get the response structure as the successful structure;
3. Insert the unsuccessful response into the DB table.

##### Successful API response

```json
{"output_ResponseCode":"INS-0","output_ResponseDesc":"Request processed successfully","output_TransactionID":"vmo3kg298v4l","output_ConversationID":"99b0efe0007648eb96fd03aa1b2a4e1f","output_ThirdPartyReference":"FT15112023131748"}
```

##### Unsuccessful API response

```json
{\"output_ResponseCode\":\"INS-10\",\"output_ResponseDesc\":\"Duplicate Transaction\",\"output_TransactionID\":\"N/A\",\"output_Conve (truncated...)
"}
```

I have already tried to change the Laravel logging config to set the 'max' option to '5000', remove the backslashes but seems like the method I have implemented is not working correctly, so I am out of ideas. If someone could share some light I would appreciate it.

##### Method to format the unsuccessful API response

```php
private function formatApiResponse($originalResponse)
{
    // Remove backslashes from the original response
    $formattedResponse = stripslashes($originalResponse);

    // Decode the formatted JSON response
    $decodedResponse = json_decode($formattedResponse, true);

    if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
        Log::channel('logs')->info('Failed to decode formatted API response JSON');
        throw new \Exception('Failed to decode formatted API response JSON');
    }

    return json_encode($decodedResponse);
}
```

##### Method to insert into the database table the unsuccessful API response

```
private function insertUnsuccessfulApiResponse($response, $apiResponse, $id)
{
    // Insert API response into the database for unsuccessful transactions
    ApiResponsesMpesa::create([
        'status_code' => $response->getStatusCode(),
        'output_ConversationID' => 'N/A',
        'output_TransactionID' => 'N/A',
        'output_ResponseDesc' => $apiResponse['output_ResponseDesc'],
        'output_ResponseCode' => $apiResponse['output_ResponseCode'],
        'output_ThirdPartyReference' => 'N/A',
        'transformed_request_id' => $id,
    ]);

    Log::channel('logs')->info('API Response for Unsuccessful Transaction inserted successfully');
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the reason  you get the response from the log and don't use the received JSON from the response?

Comment: Am I getting this right, the 3rd party payment provider sends valid JSON on a successful payment, but sends and escaped slashes response on failed payments? Have you maybe contacted them and pointed that out? Would be much easier for everyone if they didn't

Comment: @brombeer, yes it would be easier if they made the change to remove the slashes in the unsuccessful response structure however many integrators are already using their API as described above, so making this change would affect all, at this point in time for them to make this change will affect all the integrations that they have and would be a mess

Comment: And you are certain you did everything correct and not somehow messed up reading the "faulty" response?

Comment: The slashes are there to escape the quotes since you are examining the response as a plain string instead of parsing it as json - which the http client should be doing for you.

Comment: @brombeer seems like you are right something wrong with the decoding for the unsuccessful API responses. Much appreciated for the assistance identifying the issue.

Comment: @Snapey you are correct. Thank you!